# Why can't I set the width and height for my Image object?

Tags: javascript, image, object

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var surface = canvas.getContext("2d");

//creating tile
var box = {};
box.x = 0;
box.y = 0;
box.img = new Image();
box.img.src = "box_image.png";
box.img.height = "64";
box.img.width = "64";

console.log(box.img.width);
//set delay to draw boxes
setTimeout(drawBoxes, 10);

//drawing tile
function drawBoxes() {
    surface.drawImage(box.img, box.x, box.y);

}
```

I wanna know why the dimensions of my image don't seem to change even when I change the width and height of the image object. The image is a 400x400 .png but I wanna make it into a 64x64 box.

Also, I've noticed that I need to put a setTimeout function for the drawImage on canvas. Without the delay, the image doesn't appear. Could you explain why this happens?

Comment: You're not using width/height values anywhere. Take a look at the other overloaded drawImage methods.

Comment: @11thdimension Is that the only way? I seem to remember my professor setting the width and height separately.

Comment: `set delay to draw boxes` - use `box.img.addEventListener('load', drawBoxes)` instead of this hit and miss 10 millisecond timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the width and height in the [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

```
surface.drawImage(box.img, box.x, box.y, box.img.width, box.img.height);
```